# Capitalise Class Name's First Letter On Netbeans IDE Template

Tags: php, netbeans, ide

I have created a template in Netbeans 7.4 for a PHP class, but I want to ensure the class name's first letter is capitalised even if the file name is not. This -

```
class ${name}
```

doesn't do it by default as it just uses the file name. Is there a way?

Comment: Use capitalize file name, it's a good practice, and Netbeans will be capitalize class name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the job

```
${name?capitalize}
```

For more information, go there:

https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-filetemplates.html

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqTemplateVariables

Accept as answer after testing my given answer

Comment: Thanks, that answered my question precisely, though my question was slightly wrong. I meant to ask how to capitalise the first letter leaving everything else the same. The function for that is cap_first (found that here : http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html).